# Spring cloud gateway create Request ID

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Cloud gateway implementation with 2-way ssl security in place.

I would like to create a request unique ID (UUID) to be used across all the services. So far I've created a GlobalFilter which is working fine.

The issue is that I would like to use the same requestID in the implementation of the ReactiveUserDetailsService.

Is there a way to do it? or a way to create the requestID in the ReactiveUserDetailsService and then share it to all others filters/services?

```
@Component
public class RequestIdFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
   @Override
   public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
      
      final var requestId = createRequestId(); // This has to be re-used in the UserDetailsService  defined below. 
                                               // or the UserDetailsService can create it and I reuse that here

      return chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
                                  .request(exchange
                                          .getRequest().mutate()
                                          .header("id", requestId).build())
                                  .build());
   }
}

@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements ReactiveUserDetailsService {
   @Override
   public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
          
        final var myrequestId = // HERE I need the Id created by the RequestIdFilter defined above or
                                // if not possible I can create an ID here but then 
                                // I have to share it in a way 
                                // that the other services/filters can read it

        return  webClient.get()
                         .header("reqId", myrequestId )
                         .bodyToMono(MyUsre.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: Create a bean of type `ServerWebExchangeContextFilter` which puts the `ServerWebExchange` in a reactor context which you could use in `findByUsername`. Then use the reactor context to retrieve it. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/filter/reactive/ServerWebExchangeContextFilterTests.java#L65-L68 for a sample.

Comment: I tried but ServerWebExchangeContextFilter.get(context) in UserDetailsService is always null

Comment: Did you create a bean for the filter?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a little example for my case? I've updated my UserDetailsService , basically it is performing a RestCall to retreive the user. I didn't get how to use here the ServerWebExchangeContextFilter  in order to set the requyestId and then read it in my RequestIdFilter